# Splitting building outlines polygon into individual features/buildings using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, splitting, multipart

I have ONE Building Outlines Polygon where instead of all the buildings being split into their own features they are all in one feature.

How can I split these into individual features?

I would like all of them to be their own entry in the attribute table.

I can't seem to find anything.  The picture below shows my situation.

[image: Here we can see that the Building Outline Polygon is only one big feature instead of each building being one entry in the attribute table.]

Comment: you can [`explode`](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/creating-new-features/separating-a-multipart-feature.htm) multiparts to single parts

Comment: Thank you This resolved my issue!